# Como saber se uma página foi atualizada?

Tags: javascript

Quero fazer uma aplicação simplezinha que apenas cheque se uma determinada página web sofreu alguma atualização a cada 1 minuto.

Basicamente, comecei com uma requisição get com fetch e joguei pra uma variável e depois desse minuto fazer uma segunda requisição e jogava o resultado em outra variável mas na hora de executar, esqueci que algumas páginas dão erro de CORS e logo meu primeiro teste já foi uma página com o CORS bloqueado.

Existe realmente alguma forma de fazer essa aplicação de checagem de atualização de página com javascript?

Comment: Veja se ajuda [Htmldiff.js](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/tnwinc/htmldiff.js?...)

Comment: Tá, mas oq exatamente eu procuro? kkkk

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma propriedade do document chamada [lastModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified), ela retorna a data e a hora que o documento foi atualizado pela última vez, poderia utilizar um [setTimeOut](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_win_settimeout.asp) e verificar se esse valor foi alterado, porém, acredito que o ideal seria usar ferramentas do React como por exemplo [useEffect](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) ou [componentDidUpdate](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

edit: Entendi, você poderia uitilizar um scraping de dados, seria um pouco chato de configurar e não sei se seria possível receber qualquer dado por esse método, porém, acredito que seja válido você dar uma olhada, procure sobre puppeteer, aqui o [repositório](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

Comment: O problema mesmo é que o CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) impede a requisição da página, por outro servidor, então não tem como eu pegar uma resposta html pra fazer a comparação. Basicamente oq eu gostaria é uma alternativa de como pegar o html de um link específico sem ser por um fetch